# Enabling and disabling Events in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, event-handling

So basically I have an event that occurs at page load. it causes an image to follow your cursor, but on a click event I would like to disable this event, and then on a second click re-enable the mouse follow event

I tried just creating a toggle variable but it just seems to be freezing my image.
 Would .on() and .off() be appropriate here? I read the documentation but I am confused on how to implement them

I am confused as to how I would turn off an event i guess.

Jscript

```
    var enabled = true;

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).mousemove(function() {
                if (enabled) {
                    $("#rocket").stop().animate({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
                }
            });
            $(document).click(function() {
                enabled == !enabled;
            }); 
        });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bmzyK/2/)

Comment: `enabled == !enabled;` looks like a typo. Try `=` :)

Comment: I just saw that, I always figured when I was working with boolean logic i used ==

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/bmzyK/4/)**

```
var enabled = true;

$(function () {    
    var $rocket = $('#rocket');   
    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
         if (enabled) {
                $rocket.css({left: e.pageX, top: e.pageY});
         }
     }).click(function () {
         enabled ^= 1;
     });
});
```

Instead of *`animate()`* use **`.css()`**

**If you really want to add a sleek animation to your catching spacecraft:**

**[LIVE DEMO with 'animation'](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/bmzyK/9/)**

```
$(function () {  

    var $rocket = $('#rocket'),
        enabled = true,
        mX =0, mY =0,
        posX =0, posY =0,
        lazy = 20; // Smooth move

    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        mX = e.pageX;
        mY = e.pageY;  
    }).click(function(){
        enabled^=1;
    });

    intv = setInterval(function(){
        if(enabled){
            posX += (mX-posX) / lazy; // zeno's paradox equation "catching delay"
            posY += (mY-posY) / lazy;
            $rocket.css({left: posX, top: posY});
        }
    }, 10); 

});
```

Comment: Works fine, but what does ^= 1 mean?

Comment: @CoreyBuchillon It's a bit `bitwise XOR operator` and used like `^=` does the same as `enabled == !enabled;`, where 1 means boolean `true` gets shifted to `0` (false) and vice-versa.

Comment: @CoreyBuchillon added another example you might like.

Comment: that looks excellent. now i know how to not make things looks so choppy

Answer (score 1):

I might try to register and remove the handler like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function handler(e) {
        $("#rocket").css({
            left: e.pageX,
            top: e.pageY
        });
    }

    $(document).on('mousemove.cursor', handler);

    var enabled = true;
    $(document).click(function () {
        enabled = !enabled;
        if (enabled) {
            $(document).on('mousemove.cursor', handler);
        } else {
            $(document).off('mousemove.cursor');
        }

    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dvDgs/)

Comment: Excellent +1 for the on and off demonstration

Answer (score 1):

Here are minor fixes to make your code work:

```
var enabled = true;

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
                if (enabled) {
                    $("#rocket").stop().animate({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
                }
            });
            $(document).click(function() {
                enabled = !enabled;
            }); 
        });
```

The fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/bmzyK/8/

Just added param e in the mousemove event and added JQuery to the JSFiddle. Also fixed the '==' typo.

Comment: Oh nice,  how did adding the param fix everything?

Comment: You were not receiving the event 'e' in the mousemove but refering to it in the animate call.